# How can I check for a valid contact ID in my Symbian app?

Tags: c++, symbian

In my application I have two views, Main View and Contacts view, and I have a saved Contacts ID.

When I load my second view, that should access default Contacts Database using my saved ID list and get these contacts information Title, etc. It leaves because the contact has been deleted.

So, How can I check if the contact that I has its ID is exists before I try to access its fields and cause a leave ?

```
CContactDatabase* contactsDb = CContactDatabase::OpenL();           
CleanupStack::PushL(contactsDb);

for (TInt i = 0; i < CsIDs.Count(); i++)// looping through contacts.
{

   TRAPD(err, contactsDb->ReadContactL(CsIDs[i])) //---->CsIDs is an array that holds IDs

   if(KErrNotFound == err)

      {

          CsIDs.Remove(i);

      }

}
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(1,contactsDb);
```

Comment: The leave mechanism works fine doesn't it ? What else are you looking for ?

Comment: I'm looking for checking ID validity without causing a "Leave" , Because I'm checking ID Validity in my view "DoAcitvateL" which cause the view not build correctly !!.

Comment: CContactsDatabase doesn't have a function that spits out an error.All its method use the leave mechanism. Anyways , you shouldn't be doing anything in DoActivateL except activate the view. You either use an active object or do that somewhere else - not in ActivateL. As a good practice ,always separate logic and UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Abhijith for your help, and I figured out the reason behind this issue, I shouldn't call

**ReadContactL** directly under **TRAPD** under **For loop**, So I created a function that checks the ID validity

and I called it under **TRAPD**, and now my Contacts List View loads well, and invalid IDs removed from

My saved IDs list.

**Solution is to follow Symbian C++ rules when dealing with "Leave":**

```
void LoadContactsL()
    {
       CContactDatabase* contactsDb = CContactDatabase::OpenL();           
       CleanupStack::PushL(contactsDb);

       for (TInt i = 0; i < CsIDs.Count(); i++)// looping through contacts.
          {

             TRAPD(err, ChickValidContactsIDL(i)) //-->Calling IDs checking function under TRAPD

             if(KErrNotFound == err)

               {

                  CsIDs.Remove(i);

               }

         }
      CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(1,contactsDb);
  }
```

// A function that checks invalid IDs.

//**Important Symbian rule**: Return "**void**" for functions that "**Leave**" under **TRAP harness**.

```
void ChickValidContactsIDL(TInt index)
{
   CPbkContactEngine* iPbkEngine = CPbkContactEngine::NewL(&iEikonEnv->FsSession());
       CleanupStack::PushL(iPbkEngine);
       iPbkEngine->OpenContactL(CsIDs[index]);
   CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(1,iPbkEngine);           
}
```